# How to fix "Bad File Name or Number" error when saving an Excel file via macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to save my excel file using a macro and I am making use of an old macro I made a while ago - which worked just fine. But now, I am getting an error which I don't seem to understand all to well.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveFile()

    Dim strDir As String, saveDate As String, userMachine As String, Filename As String, yearDate As String, monthDate As String, filePath As String        
    Dim ws1 As Workbook

    Set ws1 = Workbooks("Template.xlsm")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    saveDate = "01/02/2019"
    yearDate = Year(saveDate)
    monthDate = Format(saveDate, "MMMM")
    saveDate = Format(saveDate, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    userMachine = "User - 12345"
    strDir = "C:\user12345\desktop\Final Results\" & yearDate & "\" & monthDate & "\" & Format(saveDate, "dd-mm-yyyy") & "\"
    filePath = ""
    Filename = userMachine & " - " & saveDate & ".xlsx"
    filePath = Dir(strDir & Filename)

    If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir strDir
        If filePath = "" Then    
            ws1.SaveAs Filename:=filePath, FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
        Else
            MsgBox filePath & " Execution File Exists"        
        End If
    Else
        If filePath = "" Then            
            ws1.SaveAs Filename:=filePath, FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
        Else
            MsgBox filePath & " Execution File Exists"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

The error is on this line `filePath = Dir(strDir & Filename)` and the error is:

> Bad File Name or Number

As far as I can see, my name for the file meets the requirements to save it so I am at a total loss here.

The original code I had was this:

```
strDir = "C:\username\desktop\" & Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Date), "dd_mm_YY") & "\"
FilePath = Dir(strDir & "myFile.xlsx")
```

Comment: Did you try "Debug.Print strDir & Filename" right before the error to check the string?

Comment: Are you sure it's a valid path? The file name appears to be fine, but I cannot check for the path of course.

Comment: @Lucas thank you for the reply. Yes I did print it out and the strings are: `C:\user12345\desktop\Final Results\2019\February\01-02-2019\` and `User - 12345 - 01-02-2019.xlsx`. No clue why this isn't valid

Comment: @TimStack Thank you for the reply. I also thought it might not be a valid path, but I removed everything up until the `2019` folder and it works fine then. As soon as `2019` is included, it bombs out. AND the folder does exist. But also, if I remember how the code is supposed to function, whether the path exists or not, it would create it otherwise make use of it as is.

Comment: And the file does not already exist? Odd. Would not know the reason why it would fall over a folder name with a (4 digit) number..

Comment: @TimStack my point exactly lol..

Comment: Where is `vbDirectory` defined?

Comment: divide and conquer - forget variables for a moment, hardcode entire path and see if it works - then embed the variables one by one. possible, OS issue which doesn't allow space in file path; also sometimes single space reads as double space.

Comment: @ZackE Thank you for the reply. For the moment it isn't "defined", but I'm not sure that it has to be.. I am using Option Explicit and it hasn't thrown an error saying the variable is not defined. Aslo, the code is failing on the line just before that..

Comment: @user2648008 Ahhh I agree so much with what you saying by hard coding and checking, unfortunately, that was my first point of call and it works up until the `Final Results` folder but as soon as I add the `2019` folder, it falls over.

Comment: kindly share a screenshot of the folder full path in explorer

Comment: @user2648008 I don't know what changed, but I restarted my PC and ran the code.. Now it is working..

Comment: okay, probably it was a OS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Bad File Name or Number means that the string you are using to save the file is not valid.

You could replace the hardcoded string to your desktop with a relative reference from a function, such as:

```
Function getDeskTopPath() As String
'Get Desktop path as string
'Command can be exchanged for other information... see list below
'AllUsersDesktop
'AllUsersStartMenu
'AllUsersPrograms
'AllUsersStartup
'Desktop
'Favorites
'Fonts
'MyDocuments
'NetHood
'PrintHood
'Programs
'Recent
'SendTo
'StartMenu
'Startup
'Templates

    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    getDeskTopPath = oShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set oShell = Nothing
End Function
```